# How to tell apache to LocationMatch opposite of this?

Tags: regex, apache

I have the following in my apache conf:

```
  <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
```

**How can I put in a directive that is the *opposite* of this?**

I tried `<LocationMatch "!^/assets/.*$">` but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With Apache 2.2 (not sure about previous versions), you can use a regular expression with a negative lookahead to match all root location URL-path directories other than `/assets` like so:

```
<LocationMatch "^(?!/assets)/[^/]+">
    ...
</LocationMatch>
```

Note that this does not include the root URL-path `/` itself.

Comment: To also include the root URL-path, simply replace the `+` with a `*`.

Comment: What if multiple exceptions are needed?

Comment: @balping - just OR them together with another group inside the negative lookahead like so: `^(?!/(?:assets|exception2|exception3))/[^/]+`

Comment: +1, just had to say thanks for this. I was pulling my hair out with plain `RewriteRule`s and this saved me.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, LocationMatch does not support negative matching :/ (you could open a Bugzilla entry for this, it would certainly be useful).

And BTW you could simply put `^/assets/` as a regex, there is no need to match the full location.

One thing you can do to work around this is to define an empty LocationMatch for `^/assets/` and then use a `<Location />`.

Comment: Yes, but you _can_ use a regex with a _negative lookahead_ to achieve the desired results. See my answer.