# LocationMatch to allow a main url excluding specific sub folder

Tags: regex, apache, locationmatch

In the httpd.conf I would like to allow a main path but disallow a particular subfolder.

Any url with this pattern must be accepted:

/app-1.0/public

/app-1.0/images

/app-1.0/

but this one must be ignored / not allowed.

/app-1.0/private

I want to use this configuration on an apache version 2.2.3. I have read that that version does not support negatives regex, but I am not sure.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `/app-1\.0/(?!private$).*`

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. I tried it but I needed to modify a little: /app-1\.0/(?!private).*

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check my answer below.

Comment: Similar question here: [How to tell apache to LocationMatch opposite of this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545680/how-to-tell-apache-to-locationmatch-opposite-of-this/8547413#8547413)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disallow any paths that start with `/app-1.0/` and then have `private`, you can use

```
^/app-1\.0/(?!private).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG4sM7/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` -start of string (remove if the text is not at the start)
- `/app-1\.0/` - a literal `/app-1.0/` text (the dot must be escaped to be treated as a literal dot)
- `(?!private)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match (=disallows) if there is a `private` text right after the current position
- `.*` - any 0+ characters other than a newline

**NOTE**: In my original comment, I suggested `/app-1\.0/(?!private$).*` pattern with a `$` after `private`. That pattern disallows (=does not match) a string that contains `/app-1.0/private` at the end (`$` is the end-of-string anchor).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work within LocationMatch, as the path passed to the handler ends up including the regexp. Tested with ``<LocationMatch "^/(?!piwik).*">``.

Comment: @PietroBattiston I do not know what your requirements are (your regex is different). If you want to match any string but the one containing `piwik`, use `<LocationMatch "^/(?!.*piwik).*">`

Comment: the aim of my regex was to get everything but the ``/piwik`` path, but I now realize I have a more general problem, sorry - when I use ``LocationMatch`` with inside a ``SetHandler uwsgi-handler``, this ends up polluting the path that is passed to my uwsgi script, so that the regex itself appears the website's links.