# Apache location but not for certain paths

Tags: apache

Is it possible to exclude certain paths from a location?

```
# first location
<Location /folder1>

# second location
<Location /folder1/folder2>
```

Locations are merged and this causes problems for my configuration.

What I want to achieve is that the first or the second Location is used to prevent merging.

Can I do this using LocationMatch?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

(taken more or less from [LocationMatch to allow a main url excluding specific sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250682/locationmatch-to-allow-a-main-url-excluding-specific-sub-folder))

```
# first location
<LocationMatch ^/folder1/(?!folder2).*>

# second location
<Location /folder1/folder2>
```